# How to List Tags :committed for Today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, sidebar, acts-as-taggable-on

```
<% tag_cloud Habit.tag_counts, %w{m} do |tag, css_class| %>
 <%= link_to tag.name, taghabits_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

The above code lists out **all** the tags for habits. But how can we get it to list out only the tags that are with habits `:committed` for today?

In the habits _form `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>` gives the User options on what days he is `:committed` to doing his habit.

```
[ ] Sunday [ ] Monday [ ] Tuesday [ ] Wednesday [ ] Thursday [ ] Friday [ ] Saturday
```

**Habit model**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    before_save :set_level
    acts_as_taggable
    serialize :committed, Array

    def levels
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        "Mastery"
        end
    end

protected
    def set_level
     self.level = levels
    end 
end
```

**Habit controller**

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
      @habits = current_user.habits
    end
  end
```

Since this code is being rendered in the sidebar we'll have to add controller logic to the ApplicationController I think, like I did with `set_top_3_goals`.

**Application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3 if logged_in?
  end

  private

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
end
```

**views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<div id="sidebarsectiontop" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheadingtop" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Today</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'habits/today' %>
</div>
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Upcoming</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'goals/upcoming' %>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your time =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined your `:committed` attribute as `serialize`, you can't query the DB directly for habits within a particular day (today), so you'll need to bring all your habits from the DB and then filter them with desired commited day like this:

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.comitted_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end
end
```

And then in your ApplicationController, since you want the sidebar to appear cross-site:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_todays_habits

  private 

  def load_todays_habits
    @user_tags = current_user.habits.comitted_for_today.tag_counts
    @all_tags  = Habit.comitted_for_today.tag_counts
  end
end
```

At last, your view you can use the first list for user tags or the last for all tags, both committed for today:

```
<% tag_cloud @user_tags, %w{m} do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, taghabits_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>

<% tag_cloud @all_tags, %w{m} do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, taghabits_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

*Extra ball*: You can improve your code and turn the class method into an scope with particular habit commitment days if you use the native array support from PostgreSQL ([see here for a good guide](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/)).

Comment: Thanks so much! For the controller code which controller should I put it in and where?

Comment: That depends on which action you want to show the tag cloud. If it's in the whole page, you can use a before_action and a method to load that variable/s in your ApplicationController.

Comment: Yea its for a sidebar that appears on all pages. Should I also put the model logic in the application controller like I did with habits?

Comment: Good answer.  I'd just add that you don't necessarily need to load all of the user's habits in order to filter them.  You could let sql handle it by replacing the `all.select` line with `where("committed like ?", "%#{today_name}%")`

Comment: hmm @keyzee are you sure that'll work properly with `serialize`?

Comment: @dgilperez I copied & pasted your code, but it isn't working. It isn't listing any of the tags out.

Comment: No errors? Can you check you copied and pasted the correct bits? Can you go to the console and check that ``Habit.comitted_for_today`` and ``User.first.comitted_for_today`` show some habits?

Comment: @dgilperez when I run `Habit.comitted_for_today` we get: `=> []`. When I run `User.first.comitted_for_today` we get: `NoMethodError: undefined method "comitted_for_today" for #<User:0x007ff28aaabcf0>`. I tripled check the code to make sure it's right.

Comment: Sorry, it was `User.first.habits.comitted_for_today`, but anyway if `Habit.comitted_for_today` is empty, then the other query will be empty as well. I just saw that you are storing the day names downcased. I'm updating my answer and you tell me if you are able to retrieve results from the DB in the console.

Comment: Awesome @dgilperez thanks for the fix! Now we got this going on: `undefined method "taggings_count" for #<Habit:0x007ffaf15a8810>`. This is in reference to lines `<% tag_cloud @user_tags, %w{m} do |tag, css_class| %>` & `<% tag_cloud @all_tags, %w{m} do |tag, css_class| %>`

Comment: Yeah, that was a `acts_as_taggable` thing. Try now.

Comment: @dgilperez I tried but no luck. I get the error with the above code

Comment: Yeah, `tag_counts` work only `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects or at the class level, but not on arrays. Another caveat of `serialize`. Check my update.

Comment: Knocking them dead @dgilperez one at a time. Now we got this error: `undefined local variable or method "comitted_for_today_ids"`

Comment: Check again the code, I remove that method name in the model AND in the  controller, just a little refactor to make it more consistent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72179/discussion-between-anthonygalli-com-and-dgilperez).